# How do I create figure which contains nested objects using Graphiti.js?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create nested objects figure in graphiti.js?

Answer (score 1):

However I was able to do that using the decoration approach and it works well.

```
ivr.shape.menu.Menu = graphiti.shape.basic.Rectangle.extend(
{
  TitleLocator : graphiti.layout.locator.Locator.extend({
        init: function(parent) { this._super(parent); },
        relocate:function(index, figure){
            var bb = this.getParent().getBoundingBox();
            var tbb = figure.getBoundingBox();
            figure.setPosition(bb.getWidth()/2-tbb.getWidth()/2,-10);
        }
    }),
  init: function( strTitle ) {
    this.subElements = {};
    this.subElements.title = new graphiti.shape.basic.Label(strTitle);
    this.addFigure(this.subElements.title, new this.TitleLocator(this));

    this.calculateSize();
  }
}
```

How wrong is that?

Comment: Besides, your sub-Elements could themselves have sub-Elements.

Answer (score 0):

nested figures are not supported at the moment.

Sorry

Andreas